# I have more than 500 members but still Server Insights is Not showing any data

Tags: server, discord

I am writing because I have 507 members in my server on Discord but No data is available for me to have visibility into how my server is doing. Discord has mentioned

> If you're someone who helps run a Community Server with more than 500 members, you may have seen a new permission pop up in your server settings: View Server Insights.

But I do not have any figures and all it shows is N/A.
Kindly help me to have the server insights data.

Answer (score 1):

> But I do not have any figures and all it shows is N/A.

That's because your server just reached 500 members so Discord doesn't have enough data about it. Just wait some days and it will display all the data you need